# How to run a numeric query when there are non-numeric values?

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame in which one column is mostly numeric, but also contains non-numeric values such as "None". I would like to run a query that returns only numeric values that are greater than some thresold. However, when I run this:

```
df = df.query('num >= 100')
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

How can I run this query correctly?

Comment: it appears the datatype of your `num` column is string. Can you print out `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @Ehsan When I print it I see that the type is "object"

Comment: then your datatype of the column is string, even if it is a numbers string. and comparing string to 100 (which is a float) raises an error. I would suggest to convert your column dtype to float and deal with None values as None or Nan and do the query. Otherwise, comparing with if condition that checks the cell dtype will result in none value output anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to do this. `df['num'].apply(f)` will return a pandas boolean series of whether each value of column 'num' is a number and greater than equal to 100.

```
def f(n):
    try:
        return n >= 100
    except:
        return False

df = df[df['num'].apply(f)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert to numeric and then filter. This will, however, also convert a string `'200'` to the number `200` and thus include this row in the result (not sure if this is what you want though):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'num': ['-', 1, 1000, None, '200']})
df[pd.to_numeric(df.num,'coerce').gt(100)]
```

Result:

```
    num
2  1000
4   200
```